# What is Quartz 3.0? And does Quartz work with C++

Tags: java, c++, quartz-scheduler

I recently got a job offer asking for quartz 3.0 developers and experience in C++/QPP and unix shell scripting. I have experience and worked with quartz 1.x and java but nowhere hav i heard about quartz 3.0 and cannot find any mentioning anywhere in the internet.
 I am wondering whether it is a whole different software named as quartz and I hence do not have any relevant experience. As prior to the interview I want be well prepared as per their requirements hence....kindly please help if you have any insights.

Comment: You should definitely accept the offer! They will tell you what it is :)

Comment: Thanks :) thats tru... just wnted to know atleast something....just the fact that is it really a quartz latest version or not...As in it would be really bad if it really was and I didnt even know that right!